# jQuery Chosen and JSF2 f:ajax render issues

Tags: jquery, jsf-2, jquery-chosen

I'm using Chosen jQuery plugin in a page.

I have a dropdown which on selection calls backbean function and popualtes the values of another dropdown using f:ajax so something like:

```
<h:selectOneListbox id="drop1"
                   value="#{myBean.drop1Value}" 
                   styleClass="chzn-select">
      <f:ajax event="valueChange" listener="#{myBean.doSomething}"
                     render="drop2"/>
      <f:selectItems value="#{myBean.drop1Values}" />
</h:selectOneListbox>

<h:selectOneListbox id="drop2" 
                    value="#{myBean.drop2Value}" 
                    styleClass="chzn-select">
      <f:selectItems value="#{myBean.drop2Values}" />
</h:selectOneListbox>
```

Problem is that on event completion drop2 gets re-rendered and i still have the old empty chosen dropdown appearing next to it like below:
[image]

I tried adding :

```
   <f:ajax event="valueChange" listener="do something"
                     render="drop2" onevent="updateDropdown" />

   function updateDropdown(event) {
      if(event.status == 'success'){
          $('.chzn-select').chosen();
      }
   }
```

but that just attaches chosen to the updated drop2. the old chosen dropdown is still there. Can someone tell me how to deal with this situation? Thanks

**possible solution?**

```
    <script>
            function updateDropDowns(event){
                if(event.status == 'success'){

                    //this line removes the previous Chosen dropdown 
                    //the problem was that when the drop2 was being updated by f:ajax render
                    // i would end up with two Chosen Divs so removing the old div before 
                    //reattaching Chosen to select component seems to do good and eliminate duplicated 
                    //chosen dropdowns!

                    $('div [id$="drop2_chzn"]').remove();
                    //this lines attaches Chosen to the updates plugin
                    $('.chzn-select').chosen();
                }
            }
        </script>
```

Comment: `listener="do something"` ??? `listener` should point to some method in your bean... like  `listener="#{myBean.doSomethig}"` are you trying to achieve ? its not clear... (hide drop1? apply style to drop2?)

Comment: @Daniel @kolossus The question has nothing to do with what the `listener` does hence i ommited/neglected adding actual code. The question is regarding jQuery Chosen plugin and how once the component is being rendered causing weird behaviour by Chosen plugin. I don't know what you guys are talking about? what `"omitted key chunks of code"`? Please avoid down-voting a question for no apparent reason - if question is not clear , say so.

Comment: @techventure what is that *weird behavior* ? how should it behave ?

Comment: @Daniel Basically on drop1 `valueChange` event the backbean retrives values of drop2 and then `render` updates the drop2 component after the ajax request is done. drop2 is attached to Chosen plugin so when it gets updated Chosen plugin does not know about it and so i have two     drop2 side to side. Old one (before the ajax event was called) and new drop2 after the `f:ajax render` updated the drop2 component.

Comment: but both your drop downs got same `styleClass` and the selector finds them both and apply the plugin , make a unique `styleClass` , like `styleClass="chzn-select-drop2"` and use it `$('.chzn-select-drop2t').chosen();`

Comment: @Daniel the screenshot is actually drop2 only. That's the problem. It becomes duplicated. i'll add more detail to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this : wrap the drop2 with a `h:panelGroup` give it an Id and render it

Instead of `render="drop2"`  do `render="drop2_wrapper"`

that *should* eliminate duplicates

Comment: thanks -i'll try that and see how it goes . I updated my question with one solution too